# Get result of a callback in a variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, variables, callback, electron

I'm in front of a huge problem that I cannot solve. I want to get the result of the function `collection.find()` of Mongodb then put the result in a variable that I could reuse in another function running independently. 
Because it's a little thorough to explain, here's the code:

```
client.connect(function (err) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    const db = client.db(myDatabase);
    const collection = db.collection(myCollection);
    collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        //docs is the final result that I want to store in a variable
    });
});

$(myInput).change(function() {
    //using docs
})
```

'docs' being the result of a callback, I don't know how to retrieve it in a variable. I tried to store the whole thing in a variable, I tried global variables but nothing works, I still get `undefined` each time I run my program.
So yes, I could run my function into the callback of `collection.find()`

```
client.connect(function (err) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        const db = client.db(myDatabase);
        const collection = db.collection(myCollection);
        collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
            $(myInput).change(function(docs) {
                //using docs
            })
        });
});
```

but since it's a function which I run a lot of time, it would call Mongo very often and that's not the best thing for performance especially since my database is running on another computer.

Comment: It's async, hence you need to call `myFunction` **inside** the .toArray callback, and pass `docs` as a function parameter (or make it global, but that wouldn't make much sense). Can you please share where myFunction is called?

Comment: I got clumsy when I write my question. myFunction is running independently and do things with docs.

Comment: Can you please share the full code then? **where is myFunctions called?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Yes I'm going to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `docs` in the global scope and assign the data after the `find` method

```
let docs;

client.connect(async err => {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  const db = client.db(myDatabase);
  const collection = db.collection(myCollection);
  try {
    // docs is now a global variable containing all of the db collection
    docs = await collection.find({});
    myFunction();
  } catch (error) {
    // do something with the error
  }
});

function myFunction(){
  console.log("print docs", docs)
}
```

Comment: myFunction is running independently which I forgot to mention. Put it in the callback could be a solution but I'm trying to do it differently (store docs in a global variable that could be reused independently in myFunction)

Comment: Do you wanna call `myFunction` from other files ?

Comment: No, only this one (I'm calling these from a script other than main.js)

Comment: Why is my solution dosen't work for you ? docs is now a global variable containing the `collection.find` data which you can do whatever you want with it.. i think you should explain what you are trying to do thats failing

Comment: I finally got your solution to work (mistake from me). Thank you a lot. I just wanted not to run myFunction in the callback but since the variable is now global I can use it independently.

Comment: Nice, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo already uses promises for async too (assuming v3+)

```
Let doc=[];

client.connect(function (err) {
assert.equal(null, err);
const db = client.db(myDatabase);
Let collection=               db.collection(myCollection);
collection.find({})
.then(results=>{
  //modify data
  doc.push(results);
  myfunction();
 }
```

});

```
 function  myFunction(){
console.log(doc)
  }
```